# TFS 2010: Is there a way to detect if a branch as been forward integrated

Tags: integration, build-process, branching-and-merging

We're using a branch by feature strategy and we're implementing gated check-ins. Following the branch by feature model a feature branch should be forward integrated from the main branch before the feature is reverse integrated back into the main branch.

My question is ... is there a way in TFS 2010 to detect if a branch has NOT been forward integrated before being reverse integrated to the main branch. I am attempting to minimize the number of merge conflicts that are encountered when merging back to the main branch so I'd like to see if there's a way to prevent merging if the branch has not been forward integrated from main.

I'm looking for a solution to the forward integration issue or advice as to if my logic is sound with what I am attempting to do. I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure you've Forward Integrated is always prudent before merging to a main branch. You should rather handle any merge conflicts in your branch before Reverse Integrating. So in that respect your logic is sound.

Figuring out if a branch has been Forward Integrated can be done by looking if any merge candidates exist from main. This can be done using the API method [VersionControlServer.GetMergeCandidates()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138934%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or using the command line tf.exe:

```
tf merge /candidate /recursive $/TeamProject/Main $/TeamProject/FeatureBranch
```